# Linked docker containers can't communicate with each other

Tags: docker, docker-compose, linux-containers

I am using docker-compose to run my application stack.

The application stack is:

1. Mongo
2. Rest Service (referred as rest-service hereafter)
3. UI Service (referred as ui-service hereafter)

Below is the snippet of my docker-compose:

```
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "17027:27017"

  rest-service:
    build: ./rest-service/
    container_name: rest
    ports:
      - "15000:5000"
    command: "/opt/app/conf/config.yml"
    links:
      - mongodb:mongo

  ui-service:
    build: ./ui-service/
    container_name: ui
    ports:
     - "18080:8080"
    links:
      - rest-service:rest
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
```

The problem I am facing over here is that my rest-service can talk to mongo container (I mean on port(27017 on docker container)), since mongo is linked to restService. But ui-service cant talk to rest-service(I mean on port(5000 on docker container)).

If I try to make ui-service talk to rest-service on host port (I mean port 15000 which listens on port 5000 of docker container), it works.
Hence, I am not able to understand why this happens.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is `rest` in the `/etc/hosts` of `ui-service`? Is `ui-service` able to ping `rest` (docker exec -ti ui-service bash -> ping rest)?

Comment: @ThomasMaier `rest` is not in `/etc/hosts` of `ui-service`
Command `docker exec -ti ui-service bash -> ping rest` gives me nothing.
Well when I connect to ui-service with command,
`docker exec -ti ui-service bash` and then on the container if I say,
`ping rest`, then I do get proper response.

Does that mean I need to add `rest` on the `/etc/hosts` of host machine?

Comment: @ThomasMaier Just verified that things do work, if I add mapping for `rest` in `/etc/hosts` file of my host machine.
But just looking if there is any other better way out?

Comment: It's not necessary to add the container's IP in the hosts `/etc/hosts` since you are not binding/mounting it in the containers. Docker should add `rest` + the container's dynamic IP to the `/etc/hosts` of ui-service when you execute the docker-compose.yml above. Can you verify that?

Comment: @ThomasMaier It doesn't adds. Well manually adding mapping for `rest` in `/etc/hosts` file of host machine resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ports` parts unless you want to access the port from outside this container network. Linked containers do not need to explicitly expose ports to each other and as you found out, it exposes them to the host. You need to either not expose the ports *or* only access the ports you are using, but through `localhost:1234` syntax (not `container-name:1234`).

Make sure you understand how you are referencing the ports, if you are using container name you will likely need *link* but if you don't want to do this, will need to use localhost and the host port.

Using link automatically allow linked containers to access ports of the container. This means any port on your mongodb can be accessed via it's container port, even if it's not exposed.

When you explicitly expose them, they are exposed to your localhost for docker, which is why some of your stuff works.

Comment: I am aware that I am exposing ports of container to my host machine, but that I have done intentionally just to verify few things. I will remove them once everything works fine.

The problem I face is that, rest-service can talk to "mongo:27017", but ui-service can't talk to rest-service as rest:8080

Comment: @Aditya are you running another service on localhost that already is using 8080?